# Header order with PHP & curl

Tags: php, curl

I am using the following PHP code to send a GET request with specific headers and a cookie:

```
$getheader = array(
    "Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*",    
    "Accept-Language: en-US",
    "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)",   
    "Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate",
    "Host: mysite.com",
    "Connection: Keep-Alive"    
);


curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://mysite.com');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $getheader);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST,0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, 'cookie.txt'); //read from the cookie
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);

curl_exec($ch);
```

It's working fine but Header is sent in wrong order like the following:

```
GET http://mysite.com/ HTTP/1.1
Cookie: remember_me=1; id=9089018083 <------ this line should be at the end
Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
Accept-Language: en-US
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0)
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Host: mysite.com
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

The cookie should be sent after the header (As what web browsers do) but in my case I don't know what's wrong. can you please help?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Why "should" it be at the bottom?

The HTTP RFC states, amongst other things:

- that the capitalization of header keys has no importance
- that the order of the headers has no importance

All this is stated quite clearly in [RFC 2616 (HTTP 1.1)](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt): page 31:

> The order in which header fields with differing field names are
> received is not significant. However, it is "good practice" to send
> general-header fields first, followed by request-header or response-
> header fields, and ending with the entity-header fields.

So, whilst curl is not producing the output you expect, it is not doing anything *wrong*. The order is arbitrary, and the reason curl does this is because it will process the cookie jar **first**, and then allow you to override any headers you like at the very end using the HEADERS setting.

So, really, if your code is picky on header order, you need to teach your code to not worry about them, as a wide variety of browsers will send a different header order. Ultimately, be lenient on reception, strict on emission.

Comment: *"Why"* ? because he wants this behavior, and he wants curl (the great general-purpose http library) to do so. The in-ordered headers can lead to entire block for his program on some websites as a bot pretending to be Firefox for example.